# Date in a for loop is not updating

Tags: python, for-loop

I am having some difficulties with this `for` loop:

```
start="06/26/2020"

for i in range(5):
    
    day = datetime.strptime(start,'%m/%d/%Y')
    start=str(day.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))
    end=start
    
    print("Day:", day, "start: ", start, "end: ", end)
    
    d=timedelta(days=i)
    next= day - d
    
    day= next
```

What I would like to achieve is to going back through time.
So starting from `06/26/2020`, setting a range of time, I would need to go back until `06/22/2020`.
The code seems working fine, but start cannot be updated, so every time I start from `06/26/2020` (outside the loop).
Can you please tell me how to fix it?

I would need to have something like this:

```
Start: 06/26/2020 End:  06/26/2020
Start: 06/25/2020 End: 06/25/2020
Start: 06/24/2020 End: 06/24/2020
Start: 06/23/2020 End: 06/23/2020
Start: 06/22/2020 End: 06/22/2020
```

I think the problem is in the loop because it does not update start's value.

Comment: That very first line `day = datetime.strptime(start, '%m/%d/%Y')` gets called at the beginning of each iteration of the loop. So `day` gets set to `start`, `start` gets set to a string representation of `day`, and then you do a bunch of other things that don't change what `start` is set to. What you probably wanted to do, since you actually do attempt to update `day` at the end of the loop and don't want that overwritten with the old value of `start`, is to call `day = datetime.strptime(...)` a single time *before* the loop starts.

Comment: thanks Nathan. I tried to set next = start but then I called start in day so I am a bit confused and I got this error: `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime` fixed with     `start=str(day.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))`, but the problem is that it does not go one day back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others stated, you keep updating the `day` with the `start` value. Also, your code could be simplified a bit.

For example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start = "06/26/2020"
day = datetime.strptime(start, '%m/%d/%Y')

for date in (day - timedelta(n) for n in range(5)):
    d = date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    print("Start: ", d, "End: ", d)
```

This outputs:

```
Start:  06/26/2020 End:  06/26/2020
Start:  06/25/2020 End:  06/25/2020
Start:  06/24/2020 End:  06/24/2020
Start:  06/23/2020 End:  06/23/2020
Start:  06/22/2020 End:  06/22/2020
```

Comment: I think the simplification of the code is one of the most important things here. The original code is doing a lot of conversions back and forth between `datetime` objects and `str` representations and using a bunch of variables. So it ends up relatively hard to track what each one is supposed to be representing at a given point in the loop. Also, `str(date.strftime(...))` is redundant since `strftime(...)` already returns a string.

Comment: Thank you so much for your good advice and simplification. You're right: too many conversion back and forth definitely.

Answer (score 1):

day = datetime.strptime(start,'%m/%d/%Y')
start=str(day.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))

The problem is that start is defined outside of the loop and day is defined each time based  on start value which is 06/26/2020